# How can I fetch random rows from my mysql table

Tags: mysql

My Sql query is :

`SELECT g.name, g.description, g.hash, g.views 
FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga, c7_groups_categories gc 
WHERE ga.groups_hash = g.hash
AND ga.groups_categories_id = gc.id 
AND g.groups_categories_id = 611

AND LOWER(ga.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')`

How can i make this query to fetch some Random row every-time it is fired.

Thanks 
Zeeshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough, ORDER BY RAND():

> SELECT g.name, g.description, g.hash, g.views FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga, c7_groups_categories gc WHERE ga.groups_hash = g.hash AND ga.groups_categories_id = gc.id AND g.groups_categories_id = 611
>   AND LOWER(ga.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%') ORDER BY RAND()

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html for performance tips

Answer (score 0):

> ORDER BY RAND()

at the end of query. Not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.name, g.description, g.hash, g.views FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga, c7_groups_categories gc WHERE ga.groups_hash = g.hash AND ga.groups_categories_id = gc.id AND g.groups_categories_id = 611
AND LOWER(ga.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%') ORDER BY RAND();
```

However this is a pretty terrible idea.